# Library name misspelled on Xcode project imported from Unity

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm working on a Unity Pro project that uses the Cardboard SDK to make an App for iPhone. I've followed all the instructions on the [Cardboard Getting Started for IOS](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/get-started-ios) page.

My problem comes when importing the project to Xcode on my Mac. The build fails with:

```
ld: library not found for -liontext
(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When checking the log, i see that all the calls to the included libraries are misspelled (It's not *liontext*, it's *libiontext*.). Somehow the build script stripped the *'bi'* in the middle. This happens for a lot of other libraries. See screenshots.

Error Log:
[image]

Actual Libraries:
[image]

Question is if there is a way i can edit the names manually somehow, or make the build pass this error. I already tried building the project several times in Unity but the same happens. Plus, i have already published my VR App to the Play Store, but Xcode is making it impossible to do the same on the App Store.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's actually normal for a library of name "libfoo.a" to be referenced on the command line as "-lfoo", and when it says "Library not found for -lfoo" it is saying it can't find a "libfoo.a" in the project's link path.  So the problem is likely not the name.  It's worth double-checking that these .a's are all present in the Xcode project, and in the Assets/Plugins/iOS directory, in case any go deleted somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is occurred because that there is something misspelled by unity in its search paths in XCode project. check your XCode project's Build Settings, look for search paths, in Library Search Paths it is written

```
//:configuration = Debug
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)" "$(SRCROOT)/Libraries" "$(SRCROOT)/Libraries\Standard Assets/Plugins/iOS"

//:configuration = Release
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)" "$(SRCROOT)/Libraries" "$(SRCROOT)/Libraries\Standard Assets/Plugins/iOS"

//:completeSettings = some
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS
```

[image]

Look for the backslash '\', replace it with slash '/' and try rebuilding your project, this solved my problem.

It should be like this:

```
//:configuration = Debug
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)" "$(SRCROOT)/Libraries" "$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/Standard Assets/Plugins/iOS"

//:configuration = Release
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)" "$(SRCROOT)/Libraries" "$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/Standard Assets/Plugins/iOS"

//:completeSettings = some
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to delete and reimport all these 4 libraries. But if this problem still occurs then,

One of the dumbest and simplest solution is to rename all four lib* files to l*. For example `libiontext.a` to `liontext.a`

I know it is very odd solution but it works :)